# Changing GUI Button text when clicked the UI Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change GUI button text when I click a UI button. onGUI() method which I have written, is below.

This method is used to create new buttons when the button is clicked and to show the Sub-parts of a tree structure.

If I show you the change I want to make in the code, for example, when I click UI Latin Button, currentPart.EnglishTitle changes like currentPart.LatinTitle. I also mentioned this part as a comment in the code

currentPart is a HumanBodyPart object. HumanBodyPart is a class that stores my nodes of my tree structure.

I give you the necessary parts of my code. If there is a missing part in the code that I have given, I can edit the desired parts.

onGUI() method is here...

```cs
    private void OnGUI()
    {

        Vector3 scale = new Vector3(Screen.width / nativeSize.x, Screen.height / nativeSize.y, 1.0f);
        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, scale);

        float spacing = 25;
        float x = 7 + spacing;
        float y = 63;

        HumanBodyPart mainBodyPart = bodyVisualizer.BodyData.Body.SubParts[0];
        List<HumanBodyPart> nextPartsToRender = new List<HumanBodyPart>(new HumanBodyPart[] { mainBodyPart });
        List<HumanBodyPart> allPartsToRender = new List<HumanBodyPart>(new HumanBodyPart[] { mainBodyPart });

        scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(7, y, 264, 485), scrollPosition, new Rect(7, y, 528, scrollPosition_y));

        while (nextPartsToRender.Count > 0)
        {

            HumanBodyPart currentPart = nextPartsToRender[0];
            nextPartsToRender.RemoveAt(0);

            //The place I want to change above is the place "currentPart.English" in a bottom line
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing + x, y, 200, 20), currentPart.EnglishTitle))
            {
                if (!currentPart.IsClicked)
                {
                    currentPart.IsClicked = true;
                    HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode showModeFullBody = HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.Invisible;
                    bodyVisualizer.ShowBody(showModeFullBody);

                    AllSubPartsAndRoot.Insert(AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count, currentPart);
                    addAllSubPartsOfClickButton(currentPart, AllSubPartsAndRoot, AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count - 1);
                    HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode showModeCurrentPart = HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.LowTransparent;

                    for (int i = 0; i < AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count; i++)
                    {
                        bodyVisualizer.ShowBodyPart(showModeCurrentPart, AllSubPartsAndRoot[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentPart.IsClicked = false;
                    List<HumanBodyPart> RemoveBodyParts = new List<HumanBodyPart>();
                    RemoveBodyParts.Insert(0, currentPart);
                    addAllSubPartsOfClickButton(currentPart, RemoveBodyParts, 1);

                    for (int i = 0; i < RemoveBodyParts.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (AllSubPartsAndRoot.Contains(RemoveBodyParts[i]))
                        {
                            bodyVisualizer.ShowBodyPart(HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.Invisible, RemoveBodyParts[i]);
                            AllSubPartsAndRoot.Remove(RemoveBodyParts[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    if (AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count == 0)
                    {
                        bodyVisualizer.ShowBody(HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.LowTransparent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count; ii++)
                        {

                            bodyVisualizer.ShowBodyPart(HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.LowTransparent, AllSubPartsAndRoot[ii]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentPart.SubParts.Count != 0)
            {

                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x - spacing + currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing, y, 20, 20), ">"))
                {
                    if (!currentPart.IsExpanded)
                    {
                        currentPart.IsExpanded = true;

                    }
                    else
                        currentPart.IsExpanded = false;
                }
                if (currentPart.IsExpanded)
                {
                    nextPartsToRender.InsertRange(0, currentPart.SubParts);
                    allPartsToRender.InsertRange(allPartsToRender.Count - 1, currentPart.SubParts);
                    scrollPosition_y = allPartsToRender.Count * spacing;
                }
            }
            y += spacing;
            index++;
        }
        // End the scroll view that we began above.
        GUI.EndScrollView();

    }
```

```
public Button turkishButton;
public Button englishButton;
public Button latinButton;
```

The above is UI buttons in the script.

Comment: can't you just say ( turkishButton.Text = "My New Text" )

Comment: No, I don't want to change turkishButton text(it is a UI button.), I want to change my GUI Button text that I create in onGUI() method when I click UI turkishButton.

Comment: is this made in unity, or is it in a winform?

Comment: in unity you can get an object like this: GameObject.Find("buttonName").GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "My new text";

Comment: is there a reason why you are using the `OnGUI` instead of the [Unity UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html)?

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't use `OnGUI` but rather the [Unity UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) system.

---

You could just have a `string` with the text to display and do e.g.

```
private string onGuiButtonLabel;

public Button turkishButton;
public Button englishButton;
public Button latinButton;

private void Awake()
{
    turkishButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{onGuiButtonLabel = "Turkish";})
    englishButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{onGuiButtonLabel = "English";})
    latinButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{onGuiButtonLabel = "Latin";})
}
```

and then in `OnGUI` you use

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing + x, y, 200, 20), onGuiButtonLabel))
```

or maybe use a kind of Dictionary with an enum like

```
public Language
{
    English,
    Turkish,
    Latin
}

private Dictionary<Language, string>() titles;

private Language curentLanguage;

// or wherever you want to initialize it
private void Awake()
{
     titles = new Dictionary<Language, string>()
     {
         {Language.English, currentPart.EnglishTitle}
         {Language.Turkish, currentPart.TurkishTitle}
         {Language.Latin, currentPart.LatinTitle}
     }

     turkishButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{curentLanguage = Language.Turkish;})
     englishButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{curentLanguage = Language.English;})
     latinButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{curentLanguage = Language.Latin;})
}
```

and then in `OnGUI` use

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing + x, y, 200, 20), titles[currentLanguage]))
```

Comment: `currentPart.EnglishTitle` or `currentPart.TurkishTitle` or `currentPart.LatinTitle` is not implemented in awake() method. currentPart is in onGUI(). I can not take out currentPart from onGUI() (like as an attribute of class). How can I handle it?

Comment: As I said in the comment I don't know where or when you get it .. just move the Initialization of the dictionary to the `OnGUI` and use the second solution with an enum then. I would even recommend to rather implement the dictionary and the Initialization into the class of `currentPart` so every part already has its own dictionary you only access. Would be more efficient. **Note** btw it is `OnGUI` (big letter `O`) **not** `onGUI`.